# Modifying a table cell's .Range.Text removes any attached comments

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I've written a small VBA program to remove trailing whitespace from MS Word table cells. It iterates through all the cells of each table and modifies their `.Range.Text` object using the command

```
C.Range.Text = myRE.Replace(C.Range.Text, "")
```

where `myRE` is a VBScript RegExp 5.5 object and `myRE.Pattern = "\s+(?!.*\w)"`. The entire program can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34879230/20670).

The program works fine except for one problem. It removes all the comments from the cells as well. Before:

[image: Screenshot before]

After (the extra space is gone, but so is the comment):

[image: Screenshot after]

Looking at the local object tree, I can see that changing `C.Range.Text` also changes `C.Range.Comments` - but why?

[image: Object tree before and after]

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Can you manually apply comments to an empty cell?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. My cells aren't empty, though.

Comment: Word stores formatting and extra information inline with text, even though it's not readily visible, so you need to be careful when deleting/replacing text. Adding a comment to an empty cell, then selecting that entire cell, and pressing delete, will delete the comment in that cell.

Comment: Any comments from the downvoters on how I could have asked a better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with Range.Text, as is the case whenever RegEx or, indeed, any function that manipulates strings is used, all formatting and other non-text characters are lost when a pure string is written back to the cell.

For example, if a single character in your cell text were formatted as Bold, the bold formatting would be lost. Or if change tracking were in the cell - it would be lost. Any Footnote or Endnote would be lost. Comments fall into this same category.

You need a different approach, one that respects how Word stores non-text information in a document. Here's a suggestion that loops the cells in a table, picks up the Range at the end of the cell, then moves the starting point of the Range back as long as a pre-defined Whitespace character is found. When this criterium is no longer met, the Range is deleted. (Note I don't know why I needed to use Range.Delete twice - the first time had no effect.)

You need to work out what for you is "whitespace". I used a space, a carriage return and a tab character. You can certainly add others to the sWhitespace string.

```
Sub RemoveWhiteSpaceEndOfCell()
  Dim cel As word.Cell
  Dim sWhitespace As String
  Dim rng As word.Range
  Dim lWhiteSpaceChars As Long

  'define what constitutes Whitespace. 
  'Here: a space, a carriage return and a tab
  sWhitespace = Chr(32) & Chr(13) & Chr(9)
  For Each cel In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells
    Set rng = cel.Range
    'set the Range to the end of the cell
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    'move the starting point back as long as whitespace is found
    lWhiteSpaceChars = rng.MoveStartWhile(sWhitespace, wdBackward)
    'Only if whitespace was found, delete the range
    If lWhiteSpaceChars <> 0 Then
        'rng.Select 'For debugging purposes
        rng.Delete
        rng.Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using this method in my VSTO add-in. A strange behavior I have found is that `MoveStartWhile` can move `rng` beyond the start of current cell. and calling `rng.Delete()` results in `Cannot edit range` error. Any idea about this?